# Unable to update/change user password after using "update_without_password" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Getting started with a small new Rails app (in order to learn), I'm having an issue after following [this Devise How-to](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password), for allowing users to edit account without password confirmation. I followed also a few other Devise How-tos, to get features like:
- There is only one User permitted
- User can login with password, and email or username
- User can edit his account without password confirmation (buggy?)
- User can have an avatar (still in progress... seems buggy too :/)

And this is finally how my code looks like:

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::RegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :one_user_registered?

  protected

  def one_user_registered?
    if ((User.count == 1) & (!admin_user_signed_in?))
      redirect_to new_admin_user_session_path
    end
  end
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    admin_profile_index_path
  end

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(admin_params)    
  end

  private

  def admin_params
    params.require(:admin_user).permit(
      :firstname,
      :lastname,
      :username,
      :email,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      :sitename,
      :twitter_id,
      :github_id,
      :avatar
    )
  end

end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :avatar_cache]
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable,
         :confirmable,
         :authentication_keys => [:login]

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login, :password, :password_confirmation

  validate :validate_username

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions.to_hash).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
      where(conditions.to_hash).first
    end
  end

  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Admin space
  namespace :admin do
    # Devise (auth)
    devise_for :users, module: 'admin', path: '', path_names: {
      sign_in: 'login',
      sign_out: 'logout',
      sign_up: 'signup',
      password: 'password'
    }

    resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
    resources :profile
    resources :articles
    resources :images, path: 'library'

    root to: 'dashboard#index'
  end

  # Public space
  resources :flux, only: [:index]
  root to: 'flux#index'

end
```

If I comment the *update_without_password* part on *registrations_controller.rb*, things seem to work again, so I guess this is me using the method in a wrong way, because of a lack of knowledge... So in advance, thanks for your help!

Comment: Apparently, my problem is related to the update_without_password method, as the change password still requires a password confirmation.

Comment: To make things easier maybe: [my repo](https://github.com/soykje/about) :)